# Multiple divs width transition with 100% fill of parent

Tags: html, css

I've got such an issue:
I want to increase hovered div width with simultaneously width decrease of his siblings. Everything works fine without setting transition property.

If I set transition and move mouse quickly. My divs don't fully fill their parent.

Here's my code:

```css
#parent {
  display: block;
  position: relative;
}
#parent .child {
  float: left;
  height: 300px;
  width: 20%;
  background-color: red;
  transition: width .5s;
}
#parent .child:nth-child(2) {
  background-color: grey;
}
#parent .child:nth-child(3) {
  background-color: green;
}
#parent .child:nth-child(4) {
  background-color: yellow;
}
#parent .child:nth-child(5) {
  background-color: brown;
}
#parent:hover .child {
  width: 17.25%;
}
#parent:hover .child:hover {
  width: 31%;
}
```

```html
<div id="parent">
  <div class="child">1</div>
  <div class="child">2</div>
  <div class="child">3</div>
  <div class="child">4</div>
  <div class="child">5</div>
</div>
```

Do you have any ideas how to solve this problem? Can I fix it with pure CSS or I should use javascript for it?

Comment: There's nothing wrong... If you move your mouse quickly, while one div is closing the other is opening. At that moment, neither is with the full width. So, they won't fill the entire parent

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Perhaps using [Flexbox](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/) would give you a smoother effect.

You can adjust the [flex](https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/f/flex/) property as you need to get the dimensions right.

```css
body,
html {
  /* for demo purposes */
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

#parent {
  display: flex;
}

#parent .child {
  height: 300px;
  flex: 1 1 auto;
  background-color: red;
  transition: all .5s;
}

#parent .child:nth-child(2) {
  background-color: grey;
}

#parent .child:nth-child(3) {
  background-color: green;
}

#parent .child:nth-child(4) {
  background-color: yellow;
}

#parent .child:nth-child(5) {
  background-color: brown;
}

#parent .child:hover {
  flex: 2 1 auto;
}
```

```html
<div id="parent">
  <div class="child">1</div>
  <div class="child">2</div>
  <div class="child">3</div>
  <div class="child">4</div>
  <div class="child">5</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Works perfect on every browser except IE, where transition is not working. But it's fine for me. Thank you very much